# ReSharper - Is there a disable command I can add to a file that will not allow reorder of type members?

Tags: resharper

Much like

```
 // ReSharper disable ConvertToAutoProperty
```

I would like to know what, if existing, I can add to particular files (and only particular files) so that fields are not sorted on code cleanup.

For more information:

- I know there are settings one can set in R# itself. This needs to work even where I don't control settings (like on other people's computers)
- I know I can make a setting to disable sorting for particular types in TypeMembersLayout. This also will not work due to the same reason.
- I only want this to happen on files I care that it doesn't happen with, not a global setting.

Comment: I've been using Resharper for years, and can say with confidence this option doesn't exist. Good idea though..

Comment: I've also been using R# since 3.0. Maybe I should send the suggestion towards the jetbrains team.

Comment: @kp - Perhaps you should make it an answer so I can accept it. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using Resharper for years, and can say with confidence this option doesn't exist. Good idea though..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Generated Code options can help you. But I didn't try it.
Go to ReSharper->Options->Code Inspection->Generated Code and add your files.
I think ReSharper leaves such files untouched.

Comment: Now there is an interesting idea. Does that carry forward to other people's resharper settings automatically? See my question for the requirements.

Comment: No, I think you would need to add your files to every VS installation.  I knew you search for an easier way. But I thought there were no better answers until now.  I did not want to bore you with things that are not matching your requirements. Sorry.